# How will the 2mb hard fork be implemented?

Tags: segwit2x

With regards to SegWit2x/BIP 91. If SegWit is successfully implemented around Aug 1 what is required from the miners in November to implement the 2mb hard fork successfully? Is it also a minimum 80% signalling via blocks on predetermined dates?

Answer (score 2):

August 1st has nothing to do with BIP 91, nor will segwit become active on August 1st due to either of BIP 148 or BIP 91. The current projected date for segwit to become active (assuming that BIP 91 is enforced) is August 24th.

The segwit2x hard fork to 8 MB block weight is currently implemented as occurring 12960 blocks following the activation of segwit. For this to happen successfully, all nodes and miners must upgrade to software that implements segwit2x. The activation will be by flag block; there is no miner signaling.

Comment: I thought it was to a 2mb block weight?

Comment: No, what the fork is supposed to do is to make the "base block size" 2 MB, up from 1 MB. To do that, they must make the block weight 8 MB as segwit uses a 4 MB block weight.

Answer (score 1):

Miners have to switch (modify/upgrade) their Bitcoin software that will raise the block limit to 2MB.

BTW Earliest SegWit activation could be at block 481824.

Comment: For a hardfork to be succesful everyone needs to switch to other software; not just miners.